# ZWoom not working properly with WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having a few issues with the ZWoom plugin on WordPress. I've tried posting in the plugins support forum with no response.

The product gallery images load as a larger size before shrinking down to the desired thumbnail size. Any idea what the cause of this is or how to fix it?

Once it's formatted properly, the first image always takes extra time to load even though it's a 100px by 100px jpg

In addition to that the plugin will not not update the large preview when the different thumbs are clicked on

Does anyone have any insight on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We have replied to your post on WordPress support forum. Request you to check the reply there.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/thumbnails-loading-strangely

Do let us know if you have any other queries.